# ¿Como hacer que aparezca un cuadro de texto al sobrevolar las opciones de un menu en html5?

Tags: css, html5

En html necesito que al sobrevolar sobre las opciones de un menú aparezca un cuadro de texto explicando que hay en cada

un ejemplo de menu el que se muestra en la imagen, quisiera que al sobrevolar cada etiqueta

apareciera un cuadro con un texto explicativo como se muestra en la imagen al sobrevolar "carteles" 
si el texo explicado es largo, no me gusta en una sola línea, me gustaría como en la foto que p.e. ocupa 3 líneas
aqui hay información pero no se acabarlo de adaptar:
[tooltips](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp)

[image: menu con descripcion en cada <li>]

este es el codigo que tengo:

```css
    .menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
    
.menu li {
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #434343;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
    
    
.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #191919;
    color: deeppink;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3 col-m-3 menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Bolsas para tiendas</li>
    <li>Cartas restaurante</li>  
    <li>Carteles</li>
    <li>Carpetas</li>
    <li>Etiquetas perforadas</li> 
    <li>Etiquetas adhesivas</li>     
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

te recomiendo que siempre pongas lo que llevas de tu codigo para que sea mas facil ayudarte.

te dejo este ejemplo utilizando tu referencia y el codigo que has actualizado, espero te sirva:

[Ejemplo Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mj9gry3r/29/)

Saludos.

Comment: gracias por ayudarme! pero no se insertarlo en las etiquetas <li>, he subido el codigo como me has dicho

Comment: @Basicmix he actualizado la respuesta cambiando el demo con tu codigo, saludos.

Comment: muchísimas gracias! funciona perfectamente!!!